# Update time ago function without refreshing the page in PHP and JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to make my time ago function update it self dynamically without refreshing the page for example: when I upload a picture and underneath the picture it's return **19 seconds ago** it will be as it is, it won't change but when I refresh the page it will be **1 minute ago** or whatever.

This is the Time Ago function in PHP which I got from **css-tricks:**

```
  function ago($time){
   $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
   $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

   $now = time();

       $difference     = $now - $time;
       $tense         = "ago";

   for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
       $difference /= $lengths[$j];
   }

   $difference = round($difference);

   if($difference != 1) {
       $periods[$j].= "s";
   }

   return "$difference $periods[$j] ago ";
}
```

How I can make it change without refreshing the page with jquery?

Comment: Instead of finding the difference in time, send the timestamp over to JavaScript and automatically update the time ago from there.

Comment: Can't I make it with AJAX?

Comment: I would recommend against it because this is something JavaScript could do fine and (1) would be smoother, (2) less hits on your server. [Check out](http://timeago.yarp.com/) this jQuery plugin if you take my suggestion.